# Making a function that puts a number in the middle of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm really new to JavaScript and I've been struggling with this code for a test to get into a coding bootcamp. I wonder if anyone had any help they could give?

```js
function putInTheMiddle(array, item) {
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    let Middle = Floor.Math(array / 2);
    array.slice(Middle, 0, item);
  }

  console.log putInTheMiddle([1, 3], 2);
  console.log putInTheMiddle([1, 2, 4, 5], 3);
}
```

I would like it to print out the arrays as `[1, 2, 3]` and `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` respectively.

Comment: Your code has numerous syntax issues, and there is no such thing as `Floor.Math` either. Even if there were, you can only floor a *number*, not an array (nor can you sensibly divide an array by 2... assuming that `array` is an array)

Comment: Why do you loop 20 times?

Comment: I think you want `Math.floor(array.length/2)`

Comment: The function doesn't return anything, so you're going to log `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I've just recently started getting into javascript and have only been through the basics.

Comment: I feel really dumb... Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the loop, that will insert the number 20 times.

The function to get the floor of a value is `Math.floor()`, not `Floor.Math()`.

You need to divide the array's length by 2, not the array itself.

The function modifies the array in place, but if you want to be able to call `console.log()` when calling the function, it needs to return the array as well.

You need to use the `splice()` method to insert into the array. `slice()` just extracts part of the array without modifying.

You need to put parentheses around the argument to `console.log()`, and this needs to be outside the function definition.

```js
function putInTheMiddle(array, item) {
  let Middle = Math.floor(array.length / 2)
  array.splice(Middle, 0, item);
  return array;
}

console.log(putInTheMiddle([1, 3], 2));
console.log(putInTheMiddle([1, 2, 4, 5], 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Math.floor` rather than `Floor.Math`:

```js
const putInTheMiddle = (array, item) => {
  let middleOfArray = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
  array.splice(middleOfArray, 0, item);
  return array;
}

console.log(putInTheMiddle([1, 3], 2));
console.log(putInTheMiddle([1, 2, 4, 5], 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.floor` with `array.length` - also, `console.log` is a function, so call it with parentheses `()`:

```js
function putInTheMiddle(array, item) {
  array.splice(Math.floor(array.length / 2), 0, item);
  return array;
}

console.log(putInTheMiddle([1, 3], 2));
console.log(putInTheMiddle([1, 2, 4, 5], 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

What the OP posted needed a few corrections which the following code reflects:

```js
function putInTheMiddle(arr, item) {
  let m = Math.floor((arr.length / 2));
  arr.splice(m, 0, item);
  return arr;
}

let arr = putInTheMiddle([1, 3], 2);
console.log(`[` + arr.join() + `]`);

let arr2 = putInTheMiddle([1, 2, 4, 5], 3);
console.log(`[` + arr2.join() + `]`);
```

The user-defined function needs to return the altered array in each case if console.log is to display the intended  result.  Note, Math is an object and `floor` is a method just as console is an object and `log` is a method. The methods require parentheses.

In order to determine the middle index of the array, you need to find its length, easily available since it is a property of the array.  After dividing the length in two, you need to round the result to the nearest integer less than or equal to its value and [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) will aid in this endeavor.

Instead of using the slice method, the code utilizes the Array object's [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method which fits the task at hand perfectly.

I concur with @Barmar that the OP does not need the for-loop.

Lastly, I use the Array object's [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)() method to join the elements into a string for easy display, which does not permanently affect the array.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are new to javascript i would like to answer this with simple methods.

```
//array is the array in which you want to insert.
//item is the value which you want to insert.
function putInMiddle(array, item){
 let index = Math.floor(array.length/2);
  //array.splice is a method which takes 3 arguments.
  //argument 1 is the index where you want to make change.
  //argument 2 is number of elements you want to remove starting from that index.
  //argument 3 is the element that you want to insert at that index.
  //In your case no element needs to be removed, hence argument 2 is 0.
 array.splice(index,0,item);
 return array; 
}

//Then you can call the function in console.log if you just want to print the value.
console.log(putInMiddle(['1','2','4','5'],'3'));
//This will print ['1','2','3','4','5']
```

The above code works perfectly if you just want to add 1 element. But what if you want to add more than one element at a time. Relax, i have got you covered for that. Use the following:

```
function putInMiddle(array, itemArr){
 let index  = Math.floor(array.length/2);
 let numItems = itemArr.length;
 for(let i=0; i<numItems; i++){
   array.splice(index,0,itemArr[i]);
   index++;
 }
 return array;
}

console.log(putInMiddle(['1','2','6','7'],['3','4','5']));
//This will print ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
```

Hope this helps!